# React / Context API / TypeScript : How to init web app and avoid UI flickering at statup?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

When a user navigate to my site, I need to initialize the React web app as follow:

1. If the incoming user has never requested the web app, I want to set the UI language to browser default (navigator.language).
2. If the incoming user has already visited the site and chosen a prefered language (lang stored in the localStorage), I want to init the UI with this language.
3. If the incoming user has an account and is already connected (token available in localStorage), I want to auto-connect him and render the app accordingly : login button transformed into a welcome message, UI language set to user preference.

To do so, I'm using React Context API and a `defaultUser` object.

**`defaultUser`:** init a default user

```js
const defaultUser = {
  language: 'en_EN',
  isConnected: false
}
```

**`Context`:** create a default context

```js
export const AppContext = createContext({
  connectedUser: defaultUser,
})
```

**`Provider`:** create the provider with default context

```js
export function AppProvider({ children }: any) {

  [...]

  const provider = {
    connectedUser
  }

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={provider}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

**`App`:** init the provider during app start up

```js
export class App extends Component {

  static contextType = AppContext

  render() {
    return (
      <AppProvider>
        <AppContainer />
      </AppProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

**`AppContainer`:** render the app

```
export class AppContainer extends Component {

  static contextType = AppContext

  componentDidMount() {
    /** If user is not connected, verify if a stored session exists and use it to connect user */
    if (!this.context.connectedUser.isConnected) {
      [...do things...]
    }
  }
```

The whole mecanism works well except an annoying thing : the web app is systematically initialized with default user values, until the `AppContainer::componentDidMount()` do the real init job.
This is causing a sort of flickering effect.

I'm struggeling for 2 days on how to fix that, trying to perform `Context` init before `<AppContainer />` rendering, and I'm stuck.

Any recommandations?

**EDIT :**
For clarity, I'm adding a diagram. Currently :

1. React App is rendered at `start`.
2. Context is initialized at `start` with default value.
3. Context is updated when `end` is reached.
4. React App is rendered again when `end`.

Any layout change during these two steps (UI language, UI modification based on user permissions) are clearly visible to the user and generate a sort of flickering.
[image: Sequence]

I found sort of a solution by simply conditionning `<AppContainer/>` loading, postponing it to the end of the sequence. However instead of having flickering I have now a lag and other unwanted side effects.

The goal would be to differ all the sequence before React Act is rendered, and after `Window` is available. Then dynamically create the Context, then render all.

I think the point would be resolved if I could dynamically create the AppContext and pass a variable to `createContext()` during App `constructor()` or maybe `componentWillMount()` (not sure when Window is available), but then TypeScript get into play with types issues and I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't share the code that initializes the context, but I suspect you put the default value to be either a hardcoded value, or `navigator.language` and therefore experience the flickering. I'd like to suggest two ways to solve this:

**Solution 1**

Perhaps instead of having a hardcoded default context you could generate the default context programmatically by accessing `localStorage.get('lang')` or similar? There is a slight drawback to this solution though: You will be mixing concerns of react and the browser, but I think in this case it's an alternative to consider, because it's very simple and obvious to the reader.

**Solution 2**

Alternatively, when calling `ReactDOM.render` you could pass down whatever you need from `localStorage` as a prop to your application and so you keep the browser related logic separate from the pure React stuff.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Hi Amit, thank you. It clearly makes sense and helped me a lot, kind of mindset reset. Finally leading to get rid of Context API. See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my follow-up after [Amit suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65149314/835158), in case it can help anyone else.

#### Init *Context* with functions

Instead of initializing `defaultUser` with hard-coded values and update it later, I set directly it with a function returning `navigator.lang` as suggested. This solved the flickering issue on UI labels.

#### Init data before `RectDOM.render`

However I still had flickering on UI components for which I have to get the appropriate state from an API call.

Eg, if the incoming user has a valid session token stored in `localStorage`, the *Login* button must be disabled. Before doing so, I need to make sure the session token is valid by an async call to the API. I didn't find a way to have it «awaited» by the *Context* init which seems to be synchronous.

That's where Amit second suggestion get into play. Instead of struggling finding a solution inside React, I did necessary processing **before** `ReactDOM.render`, then passing stuffs as props to `<Apps/>`.

This works pretty well to get and pass the data...

Except that *Context API* didn't `setSate` anymore as soon as any of its data was refering to an object from outside the *Context*. In other word using function calls is ok to init (probably by val), but reference to external objects breaks `setState`.

#### Conclusion

As my project is still in early stage, this gave me the chance to get rid of *Context API*, do the proper init as required, and code the props/states progagation with basic React.